# Authorization for Microsoft App ID failed with status code Forbidden when sending bulk messages

Tags: c#, botframework

I am trying to send a message to all my users on Facebook, but it's failing for arround 30% of the users with this error

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> 
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Authorization for Microsoft App ID **** 
failed with status code Forbidden
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.JwtTokenRefresher.<SendAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
```

and this is my code  , The code is running fine for 70% of the messages but it's failing for 30% , and I am sure the 30% didnt block the bot or something

```
MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(serviceURL, DateTime.Now.AddDays(7));
        var account = new MicrosoftAppCredentials(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MicrosoftAppId"], WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MicrosoftAppPassword"]);
        var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(serviceURL), account);


        try
        {
            msg.customerid = customerIdGuid;
            msg.subscriptionmessagelogid = logId;
            msg.messagecode = messageCode;

            msg.creationdate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(messageText))
            {
                Task.Run(async () =>
            {


                IMessageActivity message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
                message.Text = messageText;
                if (messageButton != null)
                {
                    message.Attachments = new List<Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Attachment>();
                    message.Attachments.Add(messageButton);
                }



                //defining accounts 
                var userAccount = new ChannelAccount(name: customerName, id: customerId);
                var botAccount = new ChannelAccount(name: botName, id: botId);

                //creating conversation
                var conversationId = await connector.Conversations.CreateDirectConversationAsync(botAccount, userAccount);


                message.From = botAccount;
                message.Recipient = userAccount;



                message.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: conversationId.Id.Replace("@", string.Empty));



                await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync((Activity)message);

            }).Wait();
            }


        }
```

Comment: Have the users for which the message fails communicated with the bot within the last 24 hours?  (Facebook has a rule that Proactive Messages cannot be sent after 24 hours of no communication from the user.)

Comment: No , but we have the permission and we are creating a new conversation not replying to the one .